# UI Changes made in fragment layout is not reflected in emulator.(using page Viewers to create Fragment)

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, view, android-viewpager

I am using pageviewers to create fragments.
I have defined a pageviewer in `MainActivity` Layout.

#### MainActivity.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.rakesh_kr.fullclass.BranchFeed">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_branch_feed" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I made some changes to my `FragmentLayout.xml` which are not being reflected in the emulator.

#### FragmentLayout.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/titleText"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/descText"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleText"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

My emulator is currently showing
[image]

Comment: What are the changes that you are expecting to see in your emulator?

Comment: @buczek both textViews should appear below imageView

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and building?

Comment: @buczek Yes i have tried